# Get key after matching a value in JSON

Tags: python, json

I have the below json and i'm trying to get the key value if the "following_status": is "followed". Can you help me please?

```
{
    "key1": {
        "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 06:55:55.652434",
        "following_status": "followed",
        "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
        "job_name": "blogger-following",
        "target": "name1",
        "liked": 21,
        "watched": 7,
        "commented": 0,
        "followed": false,
        "unfollowed": false,
        "scraped": false,
        "pm_sent": false
    },
    "key2": {
        "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 08:05:18.777275",
        "following_status": "none",
        "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
        "job_name": "blogger-following",
        "target": "name2",
        "liked": 16,
        "watched": 7,
        "commented": 0,
        "followed": false,
        "unfollowed": false,
        "scraped": false,
        "pm_sent": false
    },
    "key3": {
        "last_interaction": "2022-06-20 08:02:35.141878",
        "following_status": "followed",
        "session_id": "f594abec-3819-4461-9b6c-0df0f11cf382",
        "job_name": "blogger-following",
        "target": "name3",
        "liked": 9,
        "watched": 22,
        "commented": 0,
        "followed": false,
        "unfollowed": false,
        "scraped": false,
        "pm_sent": false
        }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing nor a custom tutorial service. Asking basically "Can someone help me?" isn't an actual question"  and is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: i tried the below: 


import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('json file path')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
my_dict = json.load(f)

# list out keys and values separately
key_list = list(my_dict.keys())
val_list = list(my_dict.values())

# print(key_list)
#print(val_list)

position = val_list.index("followed")
print(key_list[position])

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your attempt in it — it's unreadable down here in the comments.

Comment: `import json 
# Opening JSON file 
f = open('json file path') 
# returns JSON object as a dictionary 
my_dict = json.load(f) 
# list out keys and values separately 
key_list = list(my_dict.keys()) 
val_list = list(my_dict.values()) 

# print(key_list) 
#print(val_list) 
position = val_list.index("followed") 
print(key_list[position])`

Comment: Indentation of code is very important in Python, not the text font used — which is why it should be **put in your question**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all items has `"following_status"` key, you can try this.

`[key for key, value in obj.items() if value["following_status"] == "followed"]`

Comment: the key i want to get is the outer one = Key1,Key3

Comment: @roncam this seems like this should get you the desired output then - have you tried the solution even?

Answer (score -1):

If your json name is dict_name then you can use

```
if(dict_name["key1"]["following_status"]=="followed")
```

Comment: the key i want to get is the outer one = Key1,Key3

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data["key1"]["following_status"]
```

Comment: the key i want to get is the outer one = Key1,Key3